# Change multiselect to single select dropdown with bootstrap-multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

We have used bootstrap-multiselect.js for multiselect dropdown in application. We have the code for multiselect as `$(".select-drp").multiselect()`. Now on a condition, we have to change this multiselect dropdown to single dropdown through jquery. Please suggest a way to achieve changing multiselect dropdown to single dropdown. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove **multiple** attribute from **select** element, It would resolve your problem
If you can't, try below code but it will change all multiple select to single select, Modify as per your need

```js
$('.multiple-select.one').multipleSelect();

let tempMultipleSelect = $.fn.multipleSelect;
$.fn.multipleSelect = function () {
    this.removeAttr('multiple');    //remove attribute as per your logic
    return tempMultipleSelect.apply(this, arguments);
}

$('.multiple-select.two').multipleSelect();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/multiple-select@1.5.2/dist/multiple-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/multiple-select@1.5.2/dist/multiple-select.min.css">

<label>Multiple</label>
<select class="multiple-select one" data-placeholder="Select" multiple>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
<hr>
<label>Multiple Changed As Single</label>
<select class="multiple-select two" multiple>
    <option selected disabled>Select</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to make the checkboxes behave like a radio button group and also have the ability to have every checkbox unchecked as well, see this [section](https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#example-simulate-single) for more details. In the example, there's a button that toggles the multi-select form/to 'multiple' to/from 'single' selection behavior.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Initialize plugin
$('.select').multiselect();
// Bind <form> to reset event
$('#interface').on('reset', multiSingle);
// Define status flag
let mode = 'multiple';

// Pass event object by default
function multiSingle(e) {
  /*
  Toggle reset button class, deselect any <option>s, and destroy the plugin
  */
  $('.toggle').toggleClass('multiple, single');
  $('.select').multiselect('deselectAll');
  $('.select').multiselect('destroy');
  /*
  If mode is 'multiple'...
  ...initialize plugin...
  ...change checkbox behavior to that of a radio button group, with the 
  added benefit of unchecking the currently checked checkbox...
  ...then set mode to 'single'
  */
  if (mode === 'multiple') {
    $('.select').multiselect({
      onChange: function(option, checked) {
        let values = [];
        $('.select option').each(function() {
          if ($(this).val() !== option.val()) {
            values.push($(this).val());
          }
        });
        $('.select').multiselect('deselect', values);
      }
    });
    mode = 'single';
    /*
    Otherwise initialize plugin as it was originally and set mode to
    'multiple'
    */
  } else {
    $('.select').multiselect();
    mode = 'multiple';
  }
}
```

```css
.multiple::before {
  content: 'Single'
}

.single::before {
  content: 'Multiple'
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link href="//davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-4.5.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="//davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <form id='interface' class='container'>
    <fieldset class='row' style='display:flex'>
      <div class='btn-grp' style='margin:20px 0 0 0'>
        <select class="select" multiple="multiple">
          <option value="cheese"> Cheese </option>
          <option value="tomatoes"> Tomatoes </option>
          <option value="mozzarella"> Mozzarella </option>
          <option value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms </option>
          <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni </option>
          <option value="onions"> Onions </option>
        </select>

        <button class='btn btn-primary toggle multiple' type='reset'></button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap.bundle-4.5.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
```